# jquery color coding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some part numbers as a string.For example :
`partnumber = "a1;a2;a3"`

Now I am displaying it using `text()` function like

```
$("#id").text("Part number(s) " + partnumber+ " is shown");
```

But I want to change the color of `partnumber` only and not the full text.

So I should get something like this :

Part number(s) (some color) a1;a2;a3 (some color) is shown.
How to do this using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap it in a span and use a class to define the extra styling:

```
$("#id").html('Part number(s) <span class="your_color_classname">' + partnumber+ '</span> is shown');
```

You have to use `html()` instead of `text()` because you are inserting html not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your html a bit:

```
<div id="id">Part number(s) <span id="partnumbers"></span> is shown</div>
```

And then in jquery:

```
$("#partnumbers").html(partnumber);
```

This way you can style `#partnumbers` and `#id` separately through Css

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#partnumbers").html("Part number(s) <span style='color:red'>" +partnumber+ "</span> is shown");
```